# How to move old file with previous command

Tags: bash, find

this command finds me files which I want to move to old folder

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +1
```

now how I cann result of this command to move command

```
mv (previous files) /old
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `xargs`.

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +1 | xargs mv -I '{}' mv {} /old/
```

Comment: You meant `xargs -I '{}' mv {} /old/`

Comment: Wow, I thought it would be enough with what I wrote. Thank you, now I see it was not complete and yours is working, @anishsane.

Comment: thx anishame ur fix works perfectly

Comment: We should give this +something to @anishane! : D

Comment: I add +1 to your commend

Comment: Also add quotes around {} in mv command. :-)

Comment: I tested and worked properly without them. At least in my Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 5):

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +1 -exec mv -- '{}' /old/ +
```

Comment: ur command gives me error: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: What does `find --version` say? And did you include the `+`?

Comment: yes I include+   find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)

Comment: +1 to this answer from me. `-exec` is the option provided for this exact reason.

Comment: yea but this example doesnt work for me